# Android AsyncTask with Jsoup crashes on release version

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have this class to check if any available update in playsore it uses `Jsoup`, everything was working on `debug` but when i upload `release` version it will crash i don't really know what is the problem. Please can anyone assist me?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while
> executing doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
>
> Caused by java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.access$000(Entities.java:1)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.(Entities.java:1)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.(Document.java:3)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.(Document.java:11)
> at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.a(TreeBuilder.java:12)
> at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java)
> at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.acknowledgeSelfClosingFlag(Tokeniser.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.insertEmpty(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:5)
> at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:6)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:7)
> at com.square.android.buyer.GetVersionCode.doInBackground(GetVersionCode.java:7)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
>
> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'int java.io.Reader.read(char[])' on a null object reference
> at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:432)
> at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:348)
> at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:336)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.a(Entities.java:16)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.(Entities.java:82)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.access$000(Entities.java:1)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.(Entities.java:1)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.(Document.java:3)
> at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.(Document.java:11)
> at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.a(TreeBuilder.java:12)
> at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java)
> at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.acknowledgeSelfClosingFlag(Tokeniser.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.insertEmpty(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:5)
> at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:6)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:7)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:7)
> at com.square.android.buyer.GetVersionCode.doInBackground(GetVersionCode.java:7)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

```
public class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private String currentVersion;
    private String packageName;
    private boolean isForceUpdate;

    public GetVersionCode(Activity act, String version, boolean forceUpdate) {
        this.mActivity = act;
        this.currentVersion = version;
        this.isForceUpdate = forceUpdate;
        this.packageName = act.getPackageName();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String newVersion = null;
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer(Utils.HOST_NAME)
                .get();
            if (document != null) {
                Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                for (Element ele : element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                        for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                            newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
        super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
        if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("update", "Current version " + currentVersion + " playstore version " + onlineVersion);
           // if(Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
            if(!currentVersion.equals(onlineVersion)) {
                //show anything
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
                String alertMessage = Utils.APP_NAME + " Version " + onlineVersion + " is available on PlayStore.";
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("New Version");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage( alertMessage );
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", (dialog, which) -> {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    try {
                        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
                    }
                });
                if(!isForceUpdate) {
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("NOT NOW", (dialog, which) -> {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    });
                }else{
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                }
                alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
 checkForUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GetVersionCode gvc = new GetVersionCode(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME, true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    gvc.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                } else {
                    gvc.execute();
                }
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Which Jsoup version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.(Entities.java:1)
```

It reminds me there was a problem with loading properties files as Android resources and class `EscapeMode` was using these.
It was fixed in [Jsoup issue #959](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/959), fix released in version 1.11.1 so try using at least this version.